# Joining subnets over multiple Sonicwall interfaces

Tags: networking, sonicwall

We have two internal interfaces X3 and X4 on a SonicWall Pro 3060, firmare 3.1.0.2.

Addressing for X3 is 192.168.0.1/255.255.240.0, and addressing for X4 is 192.168.100.1/255.255.240.0. Each interface is connected to it's own switch. Recently it was decided that devices on X3 should be able to talk to X4.

I'm not a networking pro, and I ~~know~~ think that routes should be set up to allow this. Can anyone give any insight into best practice and how to execute this?

**EDIT**

Current routing configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2nn1.png

Answer (score 0):

If both internal interfaces are configured, it likely has the correct routes configured already. You'd still need to allow network X3 and X4 to talk to each other in the firewall settings.

Can you add your current routing table?

Routing decisions are made based on where the most specific route is for a particular destination. If a router has an interface that is already on the destination network, it won't bother asking it's own default gateway.

Comment: Here's a screen of my current routing config http://i.imgur.com/t2AHhl4.png

Comment: Yes that looks correct. Now you would just need to make sure that X3 and X4 trust each other. IIRC sonicwall does this with 'trusted zones' and 'trusted interfaces'.